# Securely generating a uniformly random BigInteger

Tags: .net, security, random, cryptography, biginteger

I want to securely generate a random number in the range [0, N), where N is a parameter. However, System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator only provides a GetBytes() method to fill an array with random values.

(I need the random integers for nonces used in a slightly modified version of SRP. The "slightly modified" part is out of my control, and the only reason I'm even touching crypto stuff.)

I have written a method to do this, but I'm looking for a better way or at least confirmation that I'm doing it right.

```
using System.Numerics

///<summary>Generates a uniformly random integer in the range [0, bound).</summary>
public static BigInteger RandomIntegerBelow(this System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator source, BigInteger bound) {
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(source != null);
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(bound > 0);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<BigInteger>() >= 0);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<BigInteger>() < bound);

    //Get a byte buffer capable of holding any value below the bound
    var buffer = (bound << 16).ToByteArray(); // << 16 adds two bytes, which decrease the chance of a retry later on

    //Compute where the last partial fragment starts, in order to retry if we end up in it
    var generatedValueBound = BigInteger.One << (buffer.Length * 8 - 1); //-1 accounts for the sign bit
    Contract.Assert(generatedValueBound >= bound);
    var validityBound = generatedValueBound - generatedValueBound % bound;
    Contract.Assert(validityBound >= bound);

    while (true) {
        //generate a uniformly random value in [0, 2^(buffer.Length * 8 - 1))
        source.GetBytes(buffer);
        buffer[buffer.Length - 1] &= 0x7F; //force sign bit to positive
        var r = new BigInteger(buffer);

        //return unless in the partial fragment
        if (r >= validityBound) continue;
        return r % bound;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct and unbiased. However, you may want to change it a bit, if you are after performance, and depending on the speed of the random source you are using. The idea is to mask out a few more bits so that the random value `r` is smaller than `2*bound`. If the length *in bits* of bound is `x` (length *excluding* the sign bit), then you generate a buffer of `n = ((x+8)/8)` bytes, and mask out the upper `(n*8-x)` bits. In C#, this should look like:

```
var x = BitLength(bound);
var n = ((x + 8) / 8);
var buffer = new Byte[n];
var mask = 0xFF >> (8 * n - x);
while (true) {
    source.GetBytes(buffer);
    buffer[n - 1] &= mask;
    var r = new BigInteger(buffer);
    if (r < bound)
        return r;
}
```

With this kind of code, you may have to ask more random bytes from the source, but you avoid the modular reduction (the `%` operator). A proper PRNG should be much faster than division on big integers, so this should be a better trade-off -- but this really depends on the performance of the random source, and, since it is a question of performance, it cannot be fully answered without trying. Chances are that, as part of an overall SRP implementation, it would not make any noticeable difference anyway.

I have used above a `BitLength()` function which does not seem to exist in C# (Java's `BigInteger` class has a `bitLength()` method, but apparently Microsoft forgot to include one in their big integer implementation -- which is a shame, because it seems that the implementation really includes a private field called `_bits` which maintains that value). The bit length can be computed efficiently from the representation, in bytes, of the `bound` value. Thus, the code would become something like this:

```
var buffer = bound.ToByteArray();
var n = buffer.length;
var msb = buffer[n - 1];
var mask = 0;
while (mask < msb)
    mask = (mask << 1) + 1;
while (true) {
    source.GetBytes(buffer);
    buffer[n - 1] &= mask;
    var r = new BigInteger(buffer);
    if (r < bound)
        return r;
}
```

I am using the fact that the length, in bytes, of the encoding of `bound`, as returned by `ToByteArray()`, is precisely the value of `n` that I need.

Comment: I was also surprised that there wasn't a BitLength member. I'm not particularly worried about the cost of a Mod operation, because I have to use ModPow on the resulting value anyways.

Answer (score 1):

That implementation looks correct for generating unbiased integers in a range.

Another approach would be to take the random bytes as the infinite digits in the binary fraction `0.xxxxxx...`, multiply that by `bound` and round down. It wouldn't actually take infinite digits, just as many as needed to determine what the rounded-down result is. I think that's more complex though.

But generating numbers in the full range may be unnecessary for your protocol. [RFC 5054](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054#section-3.1) section 3.1 requires only 256-bit private exponents. That number comes from doubling the bit-length of the hash output and requires that a safe prime is used. An earlier draft of that RFC referred to [On Diffie-Hellman key agreement with short exponents](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.5952&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for an explanation, which is in the first paragraph of section 4 there.

If you prefer more random bits, take the bit length of `range` minus 1. This is what OpenSSL [does for Diffie-Hellman](http://cvs.openssl.org/fileview?f=openssl/crypto/dh/dh_key.c&v=1.33) (search for `BN_rand` and the line before it). That's still easier to generate and less that twice shorter than the full range, and if that makes a difference you should use a larger prime.